# Some questions about $\operatorname{spec}( \mathbb{Z} )$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let consider the scheme $\operatorname{spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ I have some questions about this scheme :

1. For a variety $X$ defined over a field $K$, one can define the dualizing sheaf. Is there an analogue for $\operatorname{spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ ? Does $\operatorname{spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ have a "dualizing sheaf" ?
2. I know that on affine schemes the cohomology groups $H^i(\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}), \mathcal{F})$ are 0 for $i>0$ and for every quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$. And I know that invertible sheaf are quasi coherent. So let $D$ be a divisor on $\operatorname{spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, if I denote $L_D$ the invertible sheaf associated with $D$, we have $H^i( \operatorname{spec}(\mathbb{Z}), L_D)=0$ for all $i>0$. But what is the forme of the $H^0$ ? How can I describe it ?

Thanks for help

Comment: For 1), note that the dualizing sheaf is a notion for a *relative* scheme, ie a *morphism* of schemes. Even for a variety $X$, the dualizing sheaf is that of $X$ *over $K$*. Wikipedia says that, at least, every proper finitely presented morphism has a dualizing sheaf. For 2), I’d need to check again the notation, but since $L_D$ is invertible over the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}$, it’s $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}}t$ for some rational number $t$. Depending on signs, $t$ will be equal to the product of $p^{n_D(p)}$ or its inverse, where $n_D(p)$ is the “coefficient” of $p$ in $D$.

Comment: @Mindlack that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: For a Noetherian ring $R$ a finitely generated module $K$ is a dualizing module if $\operatorname{Ext}^i(R/M, K)=0$, $M$ any maximal ideal,  for $i$ not equal to the height of $M$ and is one dimensional over $R/M$ when $i$ is the height of $M$. With this definition, the dualizing module of integers is just $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer at KReiser’s request, although it would probably need an improvement – more precision, maybe.
For 1), note that the dualizing sheaf is a notion for a relative scheme, ie a morphism of schemes. Even for a variety $X$, the dualizing sheaf is that of $X$ *over $K$*. Wikipedia says that, at least, every proper finitely presented morphism has a dualizing sheaf.

For 2), I’d need to check again the notation, but since $L_D$ is invertible over the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}$, it’s $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}}t$, for some rational number $t$ (ie a rational function on $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}$). Depending on signs and conventions, $t$ will be equal to (plus or minus) the product of the $p^{n_D(p)}$ or its inverse, where $p$ runs over the prime numbers and $n_D(p)$ is the “coefficient” of the closed point corresponding to $p$ in $D$ (seen as a Weil divisor).